# mysql selecting with join to dataset and datatable in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I searched a lot but could not find the right solution.

Lets say ill select data like:

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT a.Id, a.Foo, b.Bar FROM tableA a, tableB b where a.Id = b.Id";
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    DataTable dt = ds.Tables[...]; //<== here is the problem

}
```

and I want to add this to a datatable,

**How do I call the table in this case ?**

**Is it tableA ?**

**Does it matters how I name it ?** *(could I name it foobar as well???)*

Comment: Normal an clear question, but there is allways a devoter that cant comment this.... so sad! I have no clue why this question should be closed ^^

Comment: You could name it anything in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what you are really asking for, but due to the length of comment and clarification, putting into an answer.

If you are trying to get multiple query results back from MySQL into a single "DataSet" (which can contain multiple tables), your query could contain multiple sql-statements and each would be returned into the dataset for you as different table results.  For example, if you did something like...

```
using(MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = 
@"select * from TableA;

select * from TableB;

SELECT a.Id, a.Foo, b.Bar FROM tableA a, tableB b where a.Id = b.Id;";

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

Your dataset would have 3 tables in it in direct correlation of the queries provided..

```
ds.Tables[0] = result of tableA all records.  
ds.Tables[1] = result of tableB all records.  
ds.Tables[2] = result of JOIN query tableA and tableB.
```

you could then refer to them locally however you need to...

```
ds.Tables[0].TableName = "anyLocalTableNameReference".
var t1Recs = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
```

etc...  or even create your own individual datatable variable name without having to explicitly reference the dataset and table array reference

```
DataTable myLocalTableA = ds.Tables[0];
DataTable myLocalTableB = ds.Tables[1];
DataTable myJoinResult = ds.Tables[2];
```

Hopefully this clarifies a bunch with the querying and referencing of multiple data results returned and how to then reference to the tables individually.

Comment: why is it unclear what i want ? i mean there are regular question and the statement I use is also short and showes the join. Anyways... in the end I can select it like an array if i get this right?!?!

Comment: by setting the table name `ds.Tables[0].TableName = "foobar"`, i could set it to datatable like `DataTable dt = ds.Tables['foobar'];` ?